# I am trying to launch nearby android master but give me this error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.esri.android.nearbyplaces, PID: 28905
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$zzf;
        at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.esri.android.nearbyplaces.places.PlacesFragment.setPresenter(PlacesFragment.java:154)
        at com.esri.android.nearbyplaces.places.PlacesFragment.setPresenter(PlacesFragment.java:59)
        at com.esri.android.nearbyplaces.places.PlacesPresenter.(PlacesPresenter.java:51)
        at com.esri.android.nearbyplaces.places.PlacesActivity.onCreationComplete(PlacesActivity.java:224)
        at com.esri.android.nearbyplaces.places.PlacesFragment.onCreate(PlacesFragment.java:90)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2414)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1418)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1195)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1078)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:117)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2408)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zzf" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/lib/x86, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.esri.android.nearbyplaces-eCjKJ8XXItZymb7jzSdP2g==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 33 more

Answer (score 0):

In my case I faced this error when I was working with Facebook Account Kit API for Phone number authentication. I fixed it by adding these two dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
```

Maybe you might require  to add any other similar dependency based on the services which you are using.